# Scratch Org Problems with Summer 23 Release

Tags: multi-currency, summer-23

We have automation in place that builds scratch orgs for development and testing of an application.  We dynamically generate the `project-scratch-def.json` file based on options that the developer or tester selects.  But a typical `project-scratch-def.json` file contains json that looks like this:

```
{
    "orgName": "SomeName",
    "features": ["MultiCurrency;StateAndCountryPicklist;PlatformCache;COMMUNITIES;DebugApex"],
    "namespace": "rtms",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "settings": {
        "chatterSettings": {
            "enableChatter": true
        },
        "experienceBundleSettings": {
            "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true,
            "enableOotbProfExtUserOpsEnable": true
        }
,
        "currencySettings": {
            "enableMultiCurrency": true,
            "enableCurrencyEffectiveDates": true
        }
    }
}
```

Wit the MultiCurrency feature turned on we were experiencing three types of problems (1) when we logged into the org, we landed on a white blank page and there was no way to navigate to anything on the org.  I see another case where this was posted and the conclusion put out there was that the MultiCurrency feature is deprecated.  I will need to enable this feature so if it is deprecated, then is there a new feature tag that can be used.  If anyone knows, I would love to hear about it (2) another problem is that when wen try to deploy our code which includes CONTENT ASSET metadata, we see a strange error that says "Invalid Currency: 000".  This is a strange error because this meta data makes no references to currency.  They are images.  Does anyone know what this is about.  Again if we remove multi currency this issue goes away.  But we need multi currency and we really want to keep this automated.  (3) running the cli command to create a community fails with an obsure error code.  Has anyone seen this?

Next, having removed multi currency, the "Invalid Currency: 000" errors go away.  But now we get the error:  "Invalid ISO Code CU for Country Cuba" on a meta data component called "Address".  Our source code contains one component with this name.  It is an Apex class and it doesn't make any references to country codes (especially at push/deploy time).  Has anyone else seen a similar error?

If anyone has anything to share, we would love to hear from you.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: [Looks like a platform bug](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000Pf5mXSAR).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error was reported by other customers too after Summer23.If you are trying to use the scratch org MultiCurrency feature and also Activate Multiple Currencies it breaks things resulting in the "Invalid Currency: 000" error.

Salesforce Product team has filed internal documentation bugs #W-13457345 #W-13312659 for updating [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) and [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_multicurrency) that there is no need to specify MultiCurrency feature anymore in scratch org creation since the feature is a default feature included in these Salesforce editions(Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, Developer, and Database.com Editions)

The suggestion is to add the below part in the definition file and remove "Multicurrency" from the "features" list to be able to create a scratch org.

```
"settings": {
"currencySettings": {
"enableMultiCurrency": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Swetha.  So I removed it from the features list.  We already had enableMultiCurrency but we additionally had enableCurrencyEffectiveDates (see below json).  With this, we get another error at org create time: "Effective Dated Currency could not be enabled.  Org must activate multi-currency before enabling effective dated currency."  How do we get around this?

        "currencySettings": {
            "enableMultiCurrency": true,
            "enableCurrencyEffectiveDates": true
        }

Comment: We resolved the second issue ( error "Invalid ISO Code CU for Country Cuba").   We had some automation that we forgot about that adds Address.settings-meta.xml to our source code directory before the deploy.  That defined county codes for countries that are now banned (i.e. Cuba, N. Korea and Iran).

Comment: Removing "features": ["MultiCurrency"] and adding "currencySettings": { "enableMultiCurrency": true } } is now throwing "Currency: Do not have an access to enableMultiCurrency". We are using org shape while creating scratch orgs.

Comment: There is an ongoing Salesforce investigation  #W-13595802 about the orgshape throwing `Currency: Do not have an access to enableMultiCurrency` error. We are seeing this for both package version creation and scratch org creation.Will keep you posted as I hear back

Comment: Update: [Known issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000tJ0iJAAS/) has been filed for the issue with package version creation and scratch org creation failure. Please subscribe the KI.

Comment: Please double check that Known Issue link @Swetha ?

Comment: Sorry. This is the corrected link https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000tJ0iJAAS/~