# Multicurrency cannot be enabled in scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, summer-23

Due to summer '23 release, it is now not possible to specify Multicurrency as a feature in the scratch org definition file. Therefore, it has to be enabled under settings:

"settings": {
"currencySettings": {
"enableMultiCurrency": true
}
}

However, when I try to do this I get the following error:

> Error (1): A scratch org was created with username
> XXX@example.com, but the settings failed to deploy due
> to:  Do not have an access to enableMultiCurrency

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can have multicurrency in the scratch orgs?

Update: This question is not the same as [this issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404617/scratch-org-problems-with-summer-23-release) as the solution to this is to add the multicurrency as a setting in the scratch org definition file. However, this gives an error when using shape orgs. How is this fixed when using org shapes?

Comment: Summary: there's a bug that Salesforce is working on, but you don't need to specify this setting, as it is default on in new Scratch Orgs (starting in Summer 23).

Comment: If I don't specify the setting then I get a bunch of currency errors when I deploy my metadata. Also, I don't have currency settings available in my scratch org.

Comment: I am also getting the same error, we are using org shape. Without org shape it works by removing "features": ["MultiCurrency"] and adding "currencySettings": { "enableMultiCurrency": true } }

Comment: Can you please share the settings for creating the scratch orgs via orgshape.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue introduced in the Summer '23 (v58.0) release. The feature 'MultiCurrency' is no longer valid and should be replaced with:

```
"settings": {
    "currencySettings": { "enableMultiCurrency": true }
}
```

If you receive the "Currency: Do not have an access to enableMultiCurrency" error you are likely building your scratch org with an org shape; to resolve this you will need to reach out to support and have them [enable Multi-Currency Everywhere](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381840&type=1) this will grant you permission to set the `enableMultiCurrency` flag.

I have just completed this process myself after experiencing both issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have reported is identified as a bug with the Salesforce Summer'23 release with reference `#W-13605418`. The team is working on priority to fix it.I will update this thread as I have more details on the ETA.

In the meantime, here is the known issue [link](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000tJ0iJAAS/%7E) that you can subscribe:  https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000tJ0iJAAS/~